# How to subscribe on events in SignalR in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, signalr

I want to subscribe on events using signal r and using sound effect when these events happens. How can I create this in Dart (I have JS code sample but don't really understand how to make it in Dart)

In Dart it looks like that. I have sample with data: `data:  {id: '1234', date: '2022-08-29T12:05:27.770Z', base: 'BaseNameExample', additionInfo: 'there is no example', dataId: '3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6'},`

and in Dart I am trying to do it like that using audioplayer:

```
class EventsSubsriber{
  Alarmplayer alarmplayer = Alarmplayer();

  Future<List> fetchNotifications() async {
    Logger.root.level = Level.ALL;
    Logger.root.onRecord.listen((LogRecord rec) {
      print('${rec.level.name}: ${rec.time}: ${rec.message}');
    });

    Logger? logger;

    final httpConnectionOptions = HttpConnectionOptions(
        accessTokenFactory: () => SharedPreferenceService().loginWithToken(),
        skipNegotiation: true,
        transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets);

    final hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(
          'http://securelink/home',
          options: httpConnectionOptions,
        )
        .build();
    await hubConnection.start();
    List notifications= [];
    if (hubConnection.state == HubConnectionState.Connected) {
      await hubConnection
          .invoke('GetNotifications')
          .then((value) => notifications= value as List);
      await alarmplayer.Alarm(url: 'assets/notifSound.mp3', volume: 1);
      alarmplayer.IsPlaying();
    }
    hubConnection.on('GetNotifications', (arguments) {
      if (arguments!.isNotEmpty) {
        arguments == ['id'];
        arguments == ['date'];
        arguments == ['baseNameExample'];
        arguments == ['additionInfo'];
        alarmplayer.Alarm(url: 'assets/wanted.mp3', volume: 1);
        alarmplayer.IsPlaying();
      } else {
        alarmplayer.StopAlarm();
      }
    });
    // hubConnection.keepAliveIntervalInMilliseconds = 10 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    hubConnection.onclose(({error}) {
      Logger.root.level = Level.ALL;
      Logger.root.onRecord.listen((LogRecord rec) {
        print('${rec.level.name}: ${rec.error}: ${rec.message}');
      });
      print(error);
    });
    print(notifications);
    return notifications;
  }
}
```

JS-code sample looks like this:

```
Notifications(data) {
                //console.log(data)
                this.id = data.id;
                this.date= data.date;
                this.alarm.play();
            },
```

Comment: Could you elaborate where is the problem exactly?  until here `hubConnection.on('GetNotifications'`  everything is fine?

Comment: @HKN yes, it works fine until  hubConnection.on('GetNotifications' , (this part is skipped when i tried to check  it, using logger or just prints) and I can't really understand how can I create dart code like in JS code sample with sound

Comment: I think the error coming from the method you are passing `(arguments){}` . Here I suppose you are getting the notification object and trying to add it to some list . but you're not decoding the response. And in addition to that I don't know what is the purpose of this `arguments == ['id'];
        arguments == ['date'];` ... what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Could you share the response of `GetNotifications`?

Comment: @HKN I am trying to create such logic: when a new id appears in websocket, a sound starts playing. In docs to signal r it only says that i should using hubconnection.on, but I don't understand how can I bond the new id and sound. And as sample they gave me this JS code above. Or may be I should use only argumet without object?

Comment: `arguments` is the response you are getting back from the socket. so maybe you want to try something like this `var id = arguments["id"];` and then use the id as you wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have found the solution: first of all, it is really important to check if your backend devs wrote event on websockets correctly. After all this has done, we need to create our side:

It works as usuall websocket request, so we need know which type websockets returns: Map, List, bool, String, etc and the event's name. After that I wrote this code:

```
  final hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(
          'your_url',
  
        )
        .build();
    await hubConnection.start();
    List events = [];
    hubConnection.on('EventsExample', (arguments) async {
      events = arguments as List;
    
    });
```

`argument` - return websockets event as @HKN said.
In my case I need to use event's responce in my ui, so I assigned a variable with empty lists to the websocket response. But if you do not need to show anything in the user interface, then you can write inside the event just `print(arguments)`